# Restoring APKs + data from 4.1 to 4.2.2

Tags: backup, 4.2-jelly-bean, data-transfer

I migrated from `Android 4.1` (Omega) to `Android 4.2.2` (SuperNexus) on my Samsung Galaxy S3.

Before I did the migration I did a backup of apps with `Super Backup`. After this was done I moved all the files from the `SmsContactsBackup` folder to SDCard.
After flash, I've installed `Super Backup` again from the Play store and putted the `SmsContactsBackup` folder in `/storage/emulated/0/SmsContactsBackup`. Now I see all the backups in the Super Backup app.

After I do a restore/install of an app, the settings are not being picked up by the apps.

Plague Inc.: I see the settings in `data/data/com.miniclip.plagueinc`. But the app crashes on launch.
Lazors: I see the settings in `data/data/net.pyrosphere.lazors`. But my progress is gone.

Do they need to be somewhere else? Or do I need to use some other tool which can use my previous backups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, for backing up apps or SMS, TitaniumBackup works wonderfully. I've always relied on it to get my job done. But since you've already backed up your apps, I'd suggest you to try moving your app data folder to storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ folder instead of where it is now, and if it is a .obb folder, move it to /Android/obb. It'll pick up your settings.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't fix it. Will a TitaniumBackup of an app in 4.1 work in 4.2.2? I still have a nandroid backup of previous ROM. But I also changed the recovery...

Comment: Yes, it will work. TitaniumBackup creates a folder in the sdcard for backups and as long as you have the folder, it will work well.

Comment: Correct, I now did the backups with TitaniumBackup and everything went well. Thanks :)